# Can't change the status of checkbox in GridView Flutter with Mobx

Tags: flutter, mobx

I want to add a checkbox for GirdView in Flutter. The data was fetched from API request include attribute **selected** default is **false**. When I click on the checkbox of each Item it will change value is **True** and update on UI and I use Mobx to observe these change actions. When I debugging the values were changed but UI didn't update, I really don't know the reason. I added 2 pictures for UI and Mobx model below.

API:

> ```
> {
>     "name": "HuynhDuy Phuc",
>     "birthday": "None",
>     "phone": "N/A",
>     "isSelected": false
> },
> {
>     "name": "Doan Phuc",
>     "birthday": "None",
>     "phone": "N/A",
>     "isSelected": false
> },
> {
>     "name": "Phuc Vu",
>     "birthday": "None",
>     "phone": "N/A",
>     "isSelected": false
> },
> ```

```
    final _userApiPresenter = Provider.of<UserApiPresenter>(context);
    _userApiPresenter.fetchUsersList();

Observer(
                  name: 'ListHomePage',
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return (_userApiPresenter.userAPI != null)
                        ? AnimationLimiter(
                            child: GridView.builder(
                              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                              addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                              //Determine the number of cells per row
                              gridDelegate:
                                  new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 3),
                              itemCount:
                                  _userApiPresenter.userAPI.users.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                User user =
                                    _userApiPresenter.getUser(index: index);
                                return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredGrid(
                                  position: index,
                                  duration:
                                      const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                                  columnCount: 2,
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: ScaleAnimation(
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        child: Stack(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            UserItem(
                                              name: user.name,
                                              type: user.name,
                                              phone: user.phone,
                                              birthday: user.birthday,
                                              isSelected: user.selected,
                                            ),
                                            Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                              child: Checkbox(
                                                value: user.selected,
                                                onChanged: (_) {
                                                    if(user.selected){
                                                      _userApiPresenter.changeStatusCheckBox(index: index);
                                                    } else{
                                                      _userApiPresenter.changeStatusCheckBox(index: index);
                                                    }
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder:
                                                  (BuildContext context) =>
                                                      UserDetailPage(
                                                index: index,
                                                name: user.name,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        : Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                  },
                )
```

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02vYE.png)

[Mobx model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEkt7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Observable information about users array and the user model itself is missing, but what you need to do(if already not) is:

- Make the array of users observable as well - this way any addition, deletion, etc will results in update of the number of user boxes in the UI
- Make property `selected` of `User` observable also - this way when certain user 'selected' state is effected, the UI will render the change

And something off topic:

- You don't need `@action` attribute on `getUser` method, because this method is not updating any observable data

If this answer does not solve your problem, please provide implementation of `userApi` and `User` :)

Comment: @PhucNguyen, you are welcome, this is common issue. You can mark the answer as a correct one, so it can help to other people with similar issues in future :)

Answer (score 0):

You just missing one thing.

mobX does not update UI unless you tell it main variable changed..

To do so, just add the following line of code to your `changeStatusCheckBox()`

```dart
_userAPI = _userAPI;
```